# How do I calculate enthalpy change calculations questions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy

Below is a question I'm struggling with.

> When $\pu{0.1 mol}$ of aqueous potassium hydroxide was added to $\pu{0.1 mol}$ of nitric acid, $\pu{5200 J}$ were transferred to the surroundings. What is the enthalpy change, in $\pu{kJ mol-1}$ for this reaction?
>
> $$\ce{KOH(aq) + HNO3(aq) -> KNO3(aq) + H2O(l)}$$
> **A** -52
> **B** -26
> **C** +26
> **D** +52

This is how I tried to solve the question.

$$Q = \pu{5200 J} = \pu{5.2 kJ}$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Moles} &= 0.1 + 0.1 \\
&= \pu{0.2 mol}
\end{align}

$$\Delta H = \frac{Q}{\mathrm{mol}}$$
$$\Delta H = -\frac{5.2}{0.2} = \pu{-26 kJ mol-1}$$

The answer is actually **A**. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Not all numbers, that can be added, should be added. // Would you say "Kilograms = 0.1 kg + 0.1 kg = 0.2 kg"? Wouldn't you use mass or m?

Answer (score 5):

You divide by 0.1 mol only. Think of it this way. Let's change this question to using 0.1 mol $\ce{KOH}$ and 0.2 mol $\ce{HNO3}$. Technically, this reaction should only produce $\pu{5200 J}$ still because you only used 0.1 mol of $\ce{KOH}$ which is the limiting reagent as the reagents are in a 1:1 ratio. By your logic, however, this could compute to $\pu{\frac{5200 J}{0.3 mol}} = \pu{17.3 kJ}$ which is now different than you answer of $\ce{-26 kJ}$. Therefore, you don't consider the moles as the sum of the moles of reactants. Instead, you have to look at what's limiting in this specific calculation. In this case, they are 1:1 ratio and there is 0.1 mol of each so just divide $\pu{5200 J}$ by 0.1 mol.